# Is there a reliable way to detect when all animations for a given element and its children are completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

An element will fire the animationStart and animationStartEnd events when CSS animations are declared.

Is there a way to fire a javascript function when:

1. All animations are finished, including the animations of children.
2. No animations are declared and there is no need to wait.

Here is my current approach:
http://codepen.io/miguel-perez/pen/CDcAG

```
var
/**
 * Fires a custom event when all animations are complete
 * @param   {object}    $element - jQuery object that should trigger event
 * 
 */
 triggerAllAnimationEndEvent = function ($element) {
    var animationCount      = 0,
        animationstart      = "animationstart webkitAnimationStart oanimationstart MSAnimationStart",
        animationend        = "animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd",
        eventname           = "allanimationend",
        unbindHandlers      = function(e){
            $element.trigger(eventname);
            // utility.redraw($element);
            console.log(eventname);
        },
        onAnimationStart    = function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).is($element)) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                animationCount ++;
            }
        },
        onAnimationEnd      = function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).is($element)) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                animationCount --;
                if(animationCount === 0) {
                    unbindHandlers();
                }
            }
        };

    $element.on(animationstart, onAnimationStart);
    $element.on(animationend, onAnimationEnd);
},

/**
 * Fires a custom callback when all animations are finished
 * @param   {object}    $element - jQuery object that should trigger event
 * @param   {function}  callback - function to run
 * 
 */
triggerCallback = function ($element, callback) {
    $element.one("allanimationend", callback);

    // Fires fake animation events in case no animations are used
    setTimeout(function(){
        $element.trigger("animationstart");
        $element.trigger("animationend");
    }, 100); // wait a bit
},
$elements = $('.element');



$elements.each(function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
  triggerAllAnimationEndEvent($this);
  triggerCallback($this, function(){
    $this.text((i + 1) + " DONE!");
  });
});
```

This approach is limited by the setTimeout. When an animation is not declared on an element, or when the animation has a delay higher than the timeout, the call fires at the wrong time.

Comment: Do you mean *CSS animations* or transforms and js animation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ready cake I know that tells you this. But developing classified `JavaScript` and `CSS` code you can do this. I don't know your code. So you are at your own from this point but I will leave you with few points:

- Separate logic from effect by using JavaScript/jQuery to trigger events while reserving CSS3 for the effects they trigger.
- Use `transitionend` to detect when transitions have ended, allowing for callback-like behaviour on jQuery methods that don’t allow callbacks.
- If animation is manipulated by JavaScript, trigger actions at end of script functions or loops depending on your code.
- Use `animationend` in the same way in relation to CSS3 keyframe animations.

*But in short you have to do this on your own writing animations.*

**References**

[transitionend on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/transitionend)

[animationend on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/animationend)